# placement of "only"

Tags: modifiers, only

Example: I will buy fish only if I shop at the pier

Does the placement of the "only" make the sentence ambiguous so that multiple readings of this sentence is possible?

Which word is "only" modifying?

Comment: The sentence is poorly constructed at best.  It's hard to say what the intended meaning is.

Comment: If you worry that a reader will group the restriction as *fish only*, don't. That reading would be a distortion of the more logical *buying fish solely at the pier and nowhere else*.

Comment: Strictly speaking it's ambiguous. It could mean that I buy fish and nothing else if I shop at the pier, or far more likely it means "I will buy fish at the pier and nowhere else.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the placement of the "only" make the sentence ambiguous?

No, it is the lack of punctuation:

I will buy fish only, if I shop at the pier - I will buy nothing except fish if I shop at the pier.

I will buy fish, only if I shop at the pier - (there is an implied "but") I will buy fish from nowhere other than the pier

Answer (score 0):

It is modifying the phrase "buying fish". It is adding a condition to the act of making a purchase. I believe that is not ambiguous but conditional.